# How do I solve this inheritance problem with explicit initialization?

Tags: c++, inheritance

When I'm creating a constructor for a child class I get this error under the `MyBook` method:

Constructor for 'MyBook' must explicitly initialize the base class 'Book' which does not have a default constructorclang(missing_default_ctor)
Solution.cpp(8, 7): 'Book' declared here

Here's the code below

```
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
class Book{
    protected:
        string title;
        string author;
    public:
        Book(string t,string a){
            title=t;
            author=a;
        }
        virtual void display()=0;

};

class MyBook : public Book
{
    protected:
    int price;
    string t;
    string a;

    public:
        MyBook(string t, string a, int p)
        {
            Book(t, a);
        }
};


int main() {
    string title,author;
    int price;
    getline(cin,title);
    getline(cin,author);
    cin>>price;
    MyBook novel(title,author,price);
    novel.display();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When constructing a base class object, you have to do it before entering the constructor body, which means you need to use a member-initializer-list, like this:

```
MyBook(string t, string a, int p) : Book(t, a) {}
```

Also note that in order to instantiate an object of type `MyBook`, you need to override the virtual `display` method in `MyBook`, like this:

```
void display() override {};
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/bGcMKc).

Answer (score 1):

```
MyBook(string t, string a, int p)
{
    Book(t, a);
}
```

is equivalent to:

```
MyBook(string t, string a, int p) : Book() // Initialize base class with default constructor
{
    Book(t, a); // Construct a temporary Book, unrleated to the 
                // Book sub-object of this class.
}
```

which explains the compiler error. You need to use:

```
MyBook(string t, string a, int p) : Book(t, a) // Initialize base class with the
                                               // constructor that accepts t and a
{
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are declaring a constructor to `Book` that takes parameters, which implicitly erases the default constructor of `Book`. In you derive class `MyBook`, your constructor implicitely calls the default constructor of `Book` which is deleted thus the error.

You can either:

- add a default constructor to `Book`
- call the specialized `Book` constructor in the initialization list:

```cpp
        MyBook(string t, string a, int p)
          : Book(t, a)
        {
        }
```